# Changing Billing Tier for BigQuery in Datalab

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-datalab

How do I set the billing tier for queries executed through the BigQuery APIs in Google Cloud Datalab?

Comment: [This form](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/bigquery_high_compute_queries_quota_request_form) enables you to set a project-wide default setting for maximumBillingTier so that you can run [high-compute](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#high-compute) queries that require additional resources. The other option is to override the default billing tier for your project on a per-query basis. Can you confirm that you are looking for the ability to override the default billing tier for your project on a per-query basis, as opposed to increasing the default tier for your project?

Comment: Hi @AnthoniosPartheniou, I am looking for the ability to override the default billing tier for the project at a query level.

Comment: Thanks for confirming! I'm looking into submitting a pull request for this feature.

Comment: OK, thanks! I will look out for the update.

Answer (score 0):

It is currently not possible to change the billing tier on a per-query basis in Google Datalab. I've submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/googledatalab/pydatalab/pull/54) for this feature.